# Precompile variable value

Tags: c#

From what I gather in C# documentation, there doesn't appear to be a way to #define variables like in C/C++. Is this correct? I just want to confirm that I'm not overlooking something. Essentially, I want to use a #define variable in /comments/ within my code:

```
#define _CLASS_ foo123
...

/// Here is documentation for my class _CLASS_
```

That's a totally fictitious use case, but hopefully that gets the point across.

Comment: What's the use case for compile time comments?

Comment: This wouldn't do anything in C/C++, either.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: `#define` doesn't define variables in C/C++, it defines constants. Are you trying to parameterize the documentation generation? I'd look into hooking into somebody else's documentation generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# doesn't have such a preprocessor power as in C++. [Quote](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyaad03b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) from MSDN:

> The #define preprocessing directive: In C++ the #define directive is
>   commonly used to declare constant values. In C# the #define directive
>   cannot be used for this purpose. Constants in C# are best defined as
>   enumerated types (integral values only) or as static members of a
>   class or struct. If you have several such constants, consider creating
>   a separate "Constants" class to hold them.

Comment: Yeah, I read that too - The problem is that I want to use the constant in a comment. Obviously, that's not possible with a class/enum or other constructs of the language. Precompiler is the place for this. I was hoping someone out there might have a workaround, since I'm still new to C#.

Thanks for the response!